# Why is Python 3 telling me a file doesn't exist when I'm looking right at it?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm attempting to combine many CSVs into one. When I look though the directory, Python keeps telling me:

> FileNotFoundError: File b'fhv_tripdata_2016-06.csv' does not exist

I'm looking right at the file. I do a refresh on the folder and it's still there.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

file_masks = ['fhv', 'green', 'yellow']


def combine_files(file_mask):

    file_count = 1

    for path, directories, files in os.walk('TaxiDriveData/'):
        for fn in files:
            if fn.startswith(file_mask):
                if file_count == 1:
                    final_result = pd.read_csv(fn)
                else:
                    another_file = pd.read_csv(fn, skiprows=1)
                    final_result.append(another_file)

    final_result.to_csv(os.path.join('TaxiDriveCombinedData', file_mask + 'trip_data.csv' ))

for m in file_masks:
    combine_files(m)
```

Comment: Are you running this program in the same directory as your CSV files? It looks like you may need to include the rest of the path to your TaxiDriveData/. Otherwise your program doesn't know where they are.

Comment: I am not. It's one directory down.
-Script
--TaxiDriveData
--files

Comment: OH I see what you're saying.

Comment: Working ok now?:)

Answer (score 0):

Had to add the full path.

```
for path, directories, files in os.walk('TaxiDriveData/'):
        for fn in files:
            if fn.startswith(file_mask):
                if file_count == 1:
                    final_result = pd.read_csv('TaxiDriveData/' + fn)
                else:
                    another_file = pd.read_csv('TaxiDriveData/' + fn, skiprows=1)
                    final_result = final_result.append(another_file)
```